# datetime conversion on sql server stopped working

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, datetime, types

I am puzzled by an error that came out of the blue yesterday on my production server.
I am doing a LINQ2SQL query such as:

```
var mis = from m in dtcx.valori 

                  join p in dtcx.TEPARAMs on m.PARAMCD equals p.PARAMCD
                  where  

                  blah blah blah

                  select new
                  {
                      dataRilevazione = m.dataRilevazione,
                      id =m.data>=new DateTime(2010,02,26)&&m.X==3&&m.Y==69?100: m.id, 

                       blah blha
                  };
```

this converts into SQL query which has the condition:

```
N'SELECT [t0].[dataRilevazione], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN ([t0].[data] >= @p6) AND ([t0].[X] = @p7) AND ([t0].[Y] = @p8) THEN @p9
```

with

`@p6='2010-02-26 00:00:00'`

this has worked like a charm for ages, since two days ago when it stopped working saying that there was a wrong conversion from varchar to datetime.

as a matter of fact the problem is that 2010-02-26 00:00:00 is no more converted to a date! if I try

print

```
convert(datetime,'2010-02-26 00:00:00'  )
```

I get the same error, which disappears using

```
convert(datetime,'2010-02-26 00:00:00', datetime)
```

since when all worked I did not change the user, nor its locale, nor anything that I am aware of.

what can I do?
thanks

***UPDATE:***
profiling SQL Server, linq 2 sql seems to set the correct language:

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

**so the language is set to us_english!** Why the conversion still fails is beyond me!
Every idea is appreciated...

Comment: What does `SELECT @@LANGUAGE` return? Also (this might be a typo on your behalf) in SQL Server `CONVERT ('2010-02-26 00:00:00', datetime)` will always error as this is syntactically incorrecr. You need to swap the datatype and value over (i.e., `CONVERT (datetime, '2010-02-26 00:00:00')`).

Comment: Did you set p6 parameter to datetime like DECLARE @p6 datetime?

Comment: chris, my typo
el ninho, I have no control on the SQL side since it is generated by linq2sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what locale your in as this will matter - you say it's not changed, but I'd be wary of that assumption :-) One thing to care about is that US and UK datetime formats are treated differently when in "reverse" format:

- UK locale sees the date as `yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss.fff`
- US locale sees the date as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff`

You can check the language/locale you're currently using by doing `SELECT @@LANGUAGE`.

For example, this throws an error:

```
SET LANGUAGE british
GO
SELECT CAST ('1999-01-21 10:11:12.345' AS DATETIME)
GO
```

However if you change the locale to us_english, it will parse correctly.

If you want to gurantee it's always going to be parsed as `yyyy-mm-dd`, then you need to be strict and use the full ISO spec by specifying T between the date and time, e.g.,: `1999-01-21T10:11:12.345` will parse in the same way in both locales.

Yet another fun 'gotcha' to watch out for when manipulating date/time data.

*Sidenote: no I don't know why the Microsoft think us right-pondians here in Blighty see the date as yyyy-dd-mm ... I've never encountered this format. Could be inherited from European formats?*

Comment: Ouch! Not Z between time and date, but T, Z - its between time and timezone! 8-)

Comment: Yes, the propblem is that one. The language of the use is italian, if I try to use set language english the convert works well.

The puzzle (and the problem) remains, though. Why did it work until the other day? Why other sites using the same user and link2sql still work? my problem is understood but far from solved.

Comment: I don't know if linq-to-sql modifies the language at login, but the locale used by default is that configured within the SQL login. If a DBA has changed the default language within SQL Server for the user, that may explain the problem. Unfortuantly, all we can do is speculate - it *will* be that the language/locale settings have changed, but the who/when/why it changed is going to be something specific to your situation and environment.

Comment: the DBA denies under torture, and it's plausible since all the users are created with italian locale... 
I am really afraid of changing the locale to us_english since it may fix this weird behaviour but it may break some other point.

Comment: as I wrote on an update to my question, linq2sql correctly set language to us_english! but the conversion fails nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

See the different results:

```
SET LANGUAGE English
SELECT convert(DATETIME, '2010-02-01 00:00:00')
SET LANGUAGE French
SELECT convert(DATETIME, '2010-02-01 00:00:00')
SET LANGUAGE Italian
SELECT convert(DATETIME, '2010-02-01 00:00:00')
```

Results are:

```
2010-02-01 00:00:00.000
2010-01-02 00:00:00.000
2010-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

And, as in your example using `new DateTime(2010,02,26)` with French, **Italian** or similar language can cause this error

Check session options with `DBCC USEROPTIONS` - language option especially